# SQL - Select if theres an existing row with a column with this value

Tags: sql, row

I wanna check if theres an existing row with a column with this value. I'm trying to make this code work:

```
IF COUNT(SELECT * FROM RENTALHISTORY WHERE RESMID=10380 AND RTHDISPLAYBIT='1') = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'HELLO'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'HI'
END
```

I want to check if there is a row in the `rentalhistory` table with a `resmid` of 10380 and `rthdisplaybit` of 1. I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` clause as below:

```
IF exists(SELECT 1 
          FROM RENTALHISTORY 
          WHERE RESMID=10380 
          AND RTHDISPLAYBIT='1') 
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'HELLO'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'HI'    
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just count like this in stead?

```
if (SELECT count(*) FROM RENTALHISTORY WHERE RESMID=10380 AND RTHDISPLAYBIT='1') = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'HELLO'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'HI'    
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `If exists`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RENTALHISTORY WHERE RESMID=10380 AND RTHDISPLAYBIT='1')
    Print 'Found'
ELSE
    Print 'Not found'
```